# Indexing existing relational database like Oracle using elasticsearch

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have created Spring boot integrated with elasticsearch app. Which is now able to create index for my own record which am entering in `postman` and also am able to search those record with the help of `id`.

How can i create index for my Oracle DB's record and i want to search those record with the help of id or any other column values of those records.

Please find my existing code below.

Book.java

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class Book {

    private String id;
    private String title;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

ElasticSearchConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticSearchConfiguration extends AbstractFactoryBean<RestHighLevelClient> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElasticSearchConfiguration.class);
    @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes}")
    private String clusterNodes;
    @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name}")
    private String clusterName;
    private RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient;

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        try {
            if (restHighLevelClient != null) {
                restHighLevelClient.close();
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error closing ElasticSearch client: ", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class<RestHighLevelClient> getObjectType() {
        return RestHighLevelClient.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public RestHighLevelClient createInstance() {
        return buildClient();
    }

    private RestHighLevelClient buildClient() {
        try {
            restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(
                    RestClient.builder(
                            new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
                            new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return restHighLevelClient;
    }


}
```

BookController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/books")
public class BookController {

    private BookDao bookDao;

    public BookController(BookDao bookDao) {
        this.bookDao = bookDao;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Book insertBook(@RequestBody Book book) throws Exception{
        return bookDao.insertBook(book);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Map<String, Object> getBookById(@PathVariable String id){
        return bookDao.getBookById(id);
    }

    }
}
```

BookDao.java

```
@Repository
public class BookDao {

    private final String INDEX = "bookdata";
    private final String TYPE = "books";

    private RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient;

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public BookDao( ObjectMapper objectMapper, RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.restHighLevelClient = restHighLevelClient;
    }

    public Book insertBook(Book book){
        book.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        Map<String, Object> dataMap = objectMapper.convertValue(book, Map.class);
        IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(INDEX, TYPE, book.getId())
                .source(dataMap);
        try {
            IndexResponse response = restHighLevelClient.index(indexRequest);
        } catch(ElasticsearchException e) {
            e.getDetailedMessage();
        } catch (java.io.IOException ex){
            ex.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
        return book;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getBookById(String id){
        GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(INDEX, TYPE, id);
        GetResponse getResponse = null;
        try {
            getResponse = restHighLevelClient.get(getRequest);
        } catch (java.io.IOException e){
            e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
        Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap = getResponse.getSourceAsMap();
        return sourceAsMap;
    }

    }

}
```

Maven depencencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Elasticsearch Dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client-sniffer</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Please find my input and output too :

Am inserting record via `Postman` in the below format :

Input:

```
 {
    "title": "Java Always",
}
```

Output :

```
{
    "id": "be2e497f-585f-4dff-8d07-fbcee1dc1c80",
    "title": "Java Always",
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/index.html).  It is elastic's offering for data collection and pipelining. It has a [jdbc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html) input that you can then route to an [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html) output.

A sample file might look like:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "ojdbc6.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/mydb"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "password"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM my_table"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "my_index"
  }
}
```

This should take whatever you have in `my_table` and put it into an index called `my_index`.  There are a lot of options you have (such as having the db query run on a schedule), so please check out the links.

Comment: Am we new to this logstash. how i can configure with my existing spring boot application..??

Comment: @Karthikeyan sorry for the delay.  Logstash would be a separate deployment, like deploying elasticsearch.  You can have this be a run one kind of thing (which is how the example I have is setup to be), or always up and handling new data.

Comment: I have an issue while am configuring logstash for mongodb. i have posted my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50545557/error-mongodb-jdbc-mongodriver-not-loaded-are-you-sure-youve-included-the-cor