# Error: mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver not loaded. Are you sure you've included the correct jdbc driver in :jdbc_driver_library?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

Am trying to load mogodb database to elastic search using logstash. I have written below logstash config file and executing it. 
While running the config file am getting the below error :

```
  Error: mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver not loaded. Are you sure you've included the correct jdbc driver in :jdbc_driver_library?
  Exception: LogStash::ConfigurationError
```

Am using `mongo-java-driver-3.1.0.jar` driver. Please find my logstash config code below.

```
    input {
  jdbc {

    jdbc_driver_library => "D:\1SearchEngine\data\mongo-java-driver-3.1.0.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mongodb://localhost:27017/my_db"
    jdbc_user => ""
    statement => "*"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "orders"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try with mongodb_unityjdbc_full.jar instead of ojdbc14.jar

https://github.com/michaelloliveira/traccar-mongodb/blob/master/lib/mongodb_unityjdbc_full.jar

on windows try:

try double anti slash: (without the space between)

> jdbc_driver_library =>
>   "D:\ \1SearchEngine\ \data\ \mongo-java-driver-3.1.0.jar"

or try single slash:

```
jdbc_driver_library => "D:/1SearchEngine/data/mongo-java-driver-3.1.0.jar"
```

Comment: this is not working., i guess am using some wrong mongo driver

Comment: did you try with unity jdbc? http://www.unityjdbc.com/mongojdbc/mongo_jdbc.php @Karthikeyan

Answer (score 0):

Paths on Windows are a little wonky.  I cannot verify this at the moment, but in the past I had to use a preceding `/` before the drive letter.  And then all `/` for the path separators.  So give this a try:

`jdbc_driver_library => "/D:/1SearchEngine/data/mongo-java-driver-3.1.0.jar"`